# Can flink's state shared in several stream?

Tags: state, apache-flink

I have a question about flink' state. I want to know whether state could be shared  by several stream. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A given piece of Flink state is held in a single operator. But that operator can be something like a `RichCoFlatmap` or a `CoProcessFunction`, and receive and process inputs from two streams (and you can cascade these if more than two streams are involved).

Your question is very broad, so it's not clear if this approach matches the use case you have in mind.

Comment: So if I'm storing state in a `ProcessFunction A` which then is passing out the datastream and down the pipeline I have another `ProcessFunction B`. Can `ProcessFunction B` access the state which was stored in A?

Comment: No. State can only be accessed within the operator in which it lives.